# Quero remover tudo depois de Buscar com jQuery

Tags: jquery

***Eis a url:***

.../busca?tipo=APARTAMENTO%2FAPTO+DUPLEX&area_de=&area_at=&valor_de=&valor_at=&bairro=Auxiliadora&bairros%5B%5D=AUXILIADORA&code=&enviar=`Buscar`&ord=&fespecial=&pagina=1&fespecial=novopronto&fespecial=novopronto

Gostaria de remover tudo que vem depois de `Buscar` para realizar uma nova consulta com jQuery.

```
$("#fe2").click(function(){

    var url         = window.location.href;
    ...
```

Comment: O problema disso é que, se a ordem mudar, como vai garantir que realmente removeu os itens necessários?

Comment: Na verdade a ordem só muda uma vez enquanto não se clica no botão novamente,então não influência mas foi bem remarcado!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Seguem duas soluções:

Usando split, porém tem de inserir o `Buscar` novamente:

```
var url = window.location.href.split("Buscar")[0] + "Buscar";
```

Usando regex:

```
var url = window.location.href.match(/.*Buscar/);
```